# Is it possible to create to tables that reference each other without using ALTER?

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, circular-reference

I am new to databases in general and would like to have an answer to a problem that I am facing.
I would like to know if there is away two create two tables that reference each other without creating one and Altering it later and adding the reference.

```
CREATE TABLE Cats(
name VARCHAR2(15) CONSTRAINT cat_name_nn NOT NULL,
gender VARCHAR2(1) CONSTRAINT cat_gd CHECK(gender IN('W', 'M')),
nickname VARCHAR2(15) CONSTRAINT cat_pk PRIMARY KEY,
function VARCHAR2(10) CONSTRAINT cat_fn REFERENCES Functions(function),
chief VARCHAR2(15) CONSTRAINT cat_chf REFERENCES Cats(nickname),
in_herd_sinnce DATE   DEFAULT  SYSDATE,
mice_ration NUMBER(3), 
mice_extra NUMBER(3),
band_no NUMBER(2) CONSTRAINT cat_bno REFERENCES Bands(band_no))

CREATE TABLE Bands(
band_no NUMBER(2) CONSTRAINT bd_pk PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR2(20) CONSTRAINT bd_name_nn NOT NULL,
site VARCHAR2(15) CONSTRAINT bd_site_un UNIQUE,
band_chief VARCHAR2(15) CONSTRAINT bd_chf_un UNIQUE 
    CONSTRAINT bd_chf_nm REFERENCES Cats(nickname)
```

);

As far as I remember I can not do it; I am right?

Comment: I don't think it can be done without alter, because at the moment of creating the first table, the other table doesn't exist.

Comment: Beware that when you make FK constraint cycles among tables typical SQL DBMSs have problems supporting enforcement, updates & cascades.

Comment: One can expect that this is a faq. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title.

Comment: @philipxy "...FK constraint cycles among tables typical SQL DBMSs have problems supporting enforcement, updates & cascades" -- That's so true.

Answer (score 1):

No, it cannot be done. Whichever table you `CREATE` first cannot have a foreign key to the other table as that other table does not exist yet; instead you need to create the tables and then use `ALTER TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT` to create the constraint from the first table to the second.

For example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Functions ( function VARCHAR2(10) CONSTRAINT fn_fn PRIMARY KEY );

CREATE TABLE Cats(
  name VARCHAR2(15) CONSTRAINT cat_name_nn NOT NULL,
  gender VARCHAR2(1) CONSTRAINT cat_gd CHECK(gender IN('W', 'M')),
  nickname VARCHAR2(15) CONSTRAINT cat_pk PRIMARY KEY,
  function VARCHAR2(10) CONSTRAINT cat_fn REFERENCES Functions(function),
  chief VARCHAR2(15) CONSTRAINT cat_chf REFERENCES Cats(nickname),
  in_herd_sinnce DATE   DEFAULT  SYSDATE,
  mice_ration NUMBER(3), 
  mice_extra NUMBER(3),
  band_no NUMBER(2)
);

CREATE TABLE Bands(
  band_no NUMBER(2) CONSTRAINT bd_pk PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR2(20) CONSTRAINT bd_name_nn NOT NULL,
  site VARCHAR2(15) CONSTRAINT bd_site_un UNIQUE,
  band_chief VARCHAR2(15) CONSTRAINT bd_chf_un UNIQUE 
    CONSTRAINT bd_chf_nm REFERENCES Cats(nickname)
);

ALTER TABLE CATS ADD CONSTRAINT cat_bno FOREIGN KEY ( band_no )
  REFERENCES Bands(band_no);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=51cf5ffee91bfa0946873a7379d1972f)*

Comment: Also, in many comercial products the tables are created without constraints or indexes first, then the constraints are added, and then the indexes are added; sometimes, even using separated SQL scripts. In medium to large scale databases it's not that common to create the constraints together with the tables.

Comment: There is a way to do this with the weird `CREATE SCHEMA` command, see the linked question for an example. But I agree with @TheImpaler that in practice it's more important to logically group the DDL scripts and get all the details right than it is to save a single step.

Comment: @JonHeller Wow... impressive. I don't quite see great usefulness for this, but I never though it existed.